# How to build BlackBerry application on Linux?

Tags: linux, blackberry, preverify

I've read on some development blogs that it is nearly to impossible to build BlackBerry application properly on operating systems other than Windows. Any possible workarounds on veryfication, rapc usage etc may result in serious and hidden bugs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a nice blog about BB development under Linux:
[www.slashdev.ca](http://www.slashdev.ca/category/blackberry/):
[BlackBerry Development Using Linux](http://www.slashdev.ca/2008/04/03/blackberry-development-using-linux/)
[BlackBerry Simulator in Linux – Sort of](http://www.slashdev.ca/2008/03/27/blackberry-simulator-in-linux-sort-of/)
[Simulator in Linux – Slightly More Reliable](http://www.slashdev.ca/2008/04/10/simulator-in-linux-slightly-more-reliable/)
[MDS Simulator… in Linux](http://www.slashdev.ca/2008/04/03/mds-simulator-in-linux/)
[Using sigtool in Linux](http://www.slashdev.ca/2008/03/16/using-sigtool-in-linux/)
And build it all: [BlackBerry Development with Ant & Eclipse](http://www.slashdev.ca/2007/05/30/blackberry-development-with-ant-eclipse/)

Comment: I've been there. Check out here http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/how-to-use-rapc-from-rim-dirty-details/. The most significant outcome from the article is that it is not correct to use Sun's WTK prevery tool since it is not the same as that one of RIM. You just cannot replace properly RIM implemetation, which leads to serious hidden bugs resulting in screens of death etc.

Comment: err...  BB Ant Tools use rapc for preverify, see http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs

Comment: They only provide special attribute to rapc target - exepath. Following the documentation: "Explicitly define the directory containing the preverify command used by the rapc compiler. When not defined, the systems default PATH is used."

So, it assumes that preverify tool is somewhere on the disk and provides you with means for locating it so that rapc target could invoke preverify.
But the issue remains - there's no proper replacement for RIM preverify tool on Linux.

Comment: Another extract from documentation:

"Blackberry Ant Tools use the executable jar files to run the rapc compiler and signature tool. There is nothing windows specific about these ant tasks. If you have a copy of the JDE and the J2ME preverify command somewhere in the path, the rapc compiler works fine on other operating systems (Linux, Mac OS X, etc)."

Comment: well, if locating is an issue, you can try to copy rapc, sigtool and anything else in project folder and use a relative path in bb ant task (I saw something like that once)

Comment: +1, i have downloaded plugin, its successful, but now getting error while creating a project "No BlackBerry JRE is installed. Please click "Configure JREs..." link to configure a BlackBerry JRE", can you please help me?